# WIithout $\phi$ , How can a subset form a open base for any topology?

Tags: general-topology

I am studying the defination of open bases which is :

> An open base is subset of topology which can produce all open sets By taking unions of elements of open base.

Then my first observation is that $\phi$ must belong to that open base. But my this observation completely vanishes when i read this preposition as follows

> If $X$ is an non empty discrete topology the collection of all singletons of $X$ is a base for that topology

1.There is several other definations for defination open bases like
union of all basic open sets formed complete set $X$ and if $x\in B_{1}\cap B_{2}$
, for $B_{1},B_{2}\in\mathscr B$
, then there exists $B_{3}$
such that $x\in B_{3}\subseteq B_{1}\cap B_{2}$

2. A subcollection $\mathscr B$ of a topology $\tau$ is a base for   $\tau$ iff for any point $x$ belongin to any Open set Then There ExiSt $B \in \mathscr B$ such That $x \in B \subseteq U$

**But Keeping these definations Aside , my Stack Problem is how any element Or class Of element can Generate $\phi$ if { $\phi$ } is not member Of basis.**

Comment: This does not have any sense, what is $\phi$?

Comment: 'can create all open sets' is meaningless. Be more explicit on what contradiction you are getting when $\phi$ is not in  the class.

Comment: $\phi$ is empty set .

Comment: Note that indeed we never need $\emptyset$ in the final criterion for $\mathcal{B}$.  We have an open set $U$ and $x \in U$ and need to find $B_x \in \mathcal{B}$ which contains $x$ and so is never empty. Given the criterion we can write $U = \bigcup_{x \in U} B_x$ and this is an empty union when $U$ is empty.

Comment: Yeah thanks , you helped me always alot

Comment: Henno , can you help me one more time . Is " local base " or " base at point" is same thing ? If yes , then if i take a $x \in X$ and make a collection of all open set that consists that $x$ then what is the mathematical term for this class ? Actually i know that intersection of this class may make local base at a point but can you please help me in it. If i make a different questions for this concept then many will downvote. . .if you help , i shall be highly oblighed to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty union, $\bigcup \emptyset$, i.e., the union of no elements of the basis at all, is $\emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks , cleared.